# Publish from Flux<String> into a Flux<List<String>> only when source is updated

Tags: java, server-sent-events, reactive

I would like to publish list of keys, but only when keys are modified.

With the following, it's publishing in an endless loop the values, even if nothing changed

```
    RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> commands = connection.reactive();
    return commands
            .keys(String.format(AWAITING_USER_KEY_FORMAT, "*")) // returns Flux<String>
            .collectList() // returns Mono<List<String>>
            .repeat(); // returns Flux<List<String>>
```

How could publish the list only when it changed ?

Answer (score 0):

***distinctUntilChanged*** : "suppress duplicate items emitted by an Observable"

```
RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> commands = connection.reactive();
return commands
          .keys(String.format(AWAITING_USER_KEY_FORMAT, "*"))
          .collectList()
          .repeat()
          .distinctUntilChanged();
```

This will publish the entire list of awaiting users, a response will be published whenever list is updated (element removed or added)